# How to disable bbox_inches='tight' when working with matplotlib inline in ipython notebook

Tags: python, matplotlib, ipython, jupyter-notebook

When work with matplotlib inline backend in ipython notebook, the default behavior is using bbox_inches='tight' to generate the embedded png image internally via savefig(). This eliminates the whitespace around the axes and is great in most cases.

However, sometimes one might want to (temporarily) disable this feature, for example, when (s)he wants to manually keep two figures vertically aligned (assume that we don't want to use subplot here):

```
%matplotlib inline
from pylab import *
plot(rand(100))
subplots_adjust(left=0.2) # Has no effect with inline, but works as expected with qt
figure()
plot(rand(100)*10000) # Will result in a larger left margin for this figure...
subplots_adjust(left=0.2)
```

So how to disable this behavior? Thanks~

### EDIT

To make the issue involved here more explicit (thanks to Anzel), the 2nd figure, due to more digits to be displayed in yticklabels, will have larger left margin (and smaller right margin) after automatic layout adjustment triggered by the bbox_inches='tight' option in savefig(), which is internally called by notebook to generate the embedded png output. It will effectively truncate any additional space I intentionally make with subplots_adjust(), so that the 2nd figure will seem to be shifted to the right, and not vertically "aligned" with the 1st figure.

It is easy to see what I mean---just try the code snippet above:)

The reason why I'm not using subplot/subplots here (see comments to Anzel's answer) is that in this particular case, the two figures are acutally themselves composed of tens of small subplots, plus some additional formatting/labeling. Merging them into one larger array of subplots is not trivial...

Comment: Why are you not using `matplotlib.pyplot`?

Comment: Just for convenience. I think matplotlib.pyplot.plot and pylab.plot is equivalent.

Comment: pyplot is built-in with matplotlib, you don't necessarily need to import *pylab*, is what I meant

Comment: More to the question, I don't think I totally get what you want to achieve, you want to dynamically set the axis-label to be narrower and wider in notebook?

Comment: Essentially, I want to change the left margin of the axes (from the default 0.1 to 0.2), so that the axes frame/bbox of both figures are visually aligned, in notebook.

Comment: I finally got what you meant by "align" after plotting the figures on my notebook. Answer added

Comment: another update has been added to answer which hopefully fulfills your requirements

Answer (score 7):

There's a fuller answer here: [Matplotlib and Ipython-notebook: Displaying exactly the figure that will be saved](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37864735/matplotlib-and-ipython-notebook-displaying-exactly-the-figure-that-will-be-save)

The trick is to turn off the `bbox_inches='tight'` setting in ipython. It's a bit awkward to do temporarily, but just run the IPython magic in a block: `%config InlineBackend.print_figure_kwargs = {'bbox_inches':None}`

If you want to switch back to the normal way, where axis labels are automatically never cut, you can run `%config InlineBackend.print_figure_kwargs = {'bbox_inches':'tight'}` but it has to be after the block where you do the plotting that needs precise bounding boxes.

Answer (score 1):

You may use `pyplot.subplots` to align the plots in a grid order, so the figures will be visually aligned in notebook (if that's what you want?)

Something like this:

```
%matplotlib inline
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

d1 = np.random.rand(100)
d2 = np.random.rand(100)*10000

fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(nrows=2, ncols=1)
plt.subplots_adjust(left=0.2)
ax1.plot(d1)
ax2.plot(d2)
```

#### Updates

As OP's requirements to use separate plots rather than subplots, here is a hacky solution. This is working on my Notebook, more details about the customization can be found [HERE](http://matplotlib.org/users/customizing.html).

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

%matplotlib inline

# to override ytick.major.width before any plot
plt.rcParams['ytick.major.pad'] = 20
plt.plot(np.random.rand(100))

# another override to set alignment for the plot 
plt.rcParams['ytick.major.pad'] = 5
plt.figure()
plt.plot(np.random.rand(100)*10000)
```

[image: The Plots]

```
# plt.rcdefaults() will reset everything to defaults as the doc says.
```

Not the most elegant way but it's working as required.

Comment: Thanks, Anzel~ subplot/subplots is indeed the obvious way to go. However, as I mentioned in the question, sometimes we don't want to use this option. In my case, the two figures are themselves composed of tens of small subplots, plus some additional formatting/labeling. Merging them into one larger array of subplots is not trivial, and thus is preferable to operate at the figure level. The only thing needs to be done is adjusting the left margin of the axes, which is easy with subplots_adjust in qt backend. But with inline backend, bbox_inches='tight' option internally used will disturb this.

Comment: @herrlich10, I finally found a rather hacky solution. see my updates