# Matplotlib figsize not respected

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to make a square plot with matplotlib. That is, I want the whole figure to be square. When I use the following code, the width of the resulting image is still a bit larger than the height. Why is matplotlib not respecting the figsize I provide?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10, 10))

# When inspecting in browser, reveals 611x580 px image
ax.plot([1,2,3], [1,2,3])
```

Edit: I display the image inline in a Jupyter notebook, and just use the Chrome developer tools to inspect the image.

Comment: How do you produce the image that you then "inspect"?

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest I added more info.

Comment: @user2413548: not really

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That is a problem of jupyter notebook. The figure it shows is a "saved" version, which uses the `bbox_inches="tight"` option and hence changes the size of the shown image.

One option you have is to save the figure manually to png,

```
fig.savefig("output.png")
```

As @EvgenyPogrebnyak commented, the other option is to deactivate the `"tight"` option in the notebook as

```
%matplotlib inline
%config InlineBackend.print_figure_kwargs = {'bbox_inches':None}
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10, 10))

# When inspecting in browser, 
ax.plot([1,2,3], [1,2,3])  # now reveals 720 x 720 px image
```

as seen in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44098692/4124317).

Comment: also can try resetting the 'ticght' option in the notebook: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26714626/how-to-disable-bbox-inches-tight-when-working-with-matplotlib-inline-in-ipytho

Comment: @EvgenyPogrebnyak very good point. Added this to the answer (unless you want to provide your own answer with this info?)

Comment: lets keep the useful information in one single answer