# matplotlib inline backend doesn't let me control the axes position

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook

I am trying to adjust the position of the axes in my matplotlib figure.
Here are the two cells I'm running consequently in the jupyter notebook:

```py
%matplotlib inline
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

```py
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(4, 4))
ax = fig.add_axes([0.65, 0.1, 0.3, 0.8])
ax.patch.set_facecolor('red')
fig.patch.set_facecolor('blue')
```

The result however doesn't look as I expect it to:

[image]

I.e. both the figure aspect ratio and the position of the axes on it have been changed.

If, however, I change the backend from `inline` to `notebook` in the very first line (the `%matplotlib` magic) and run the same code (in a clean kernel), I do get the result as expected:

[image]

I am guessing there is some automatic adjustment function enabled in the `inline` backend, but I failed to find it. For example, I checked that `matplotlib.rcParams['figure.autolayout']` parameter is set to `False`.

Is there any way to disable this feature for the `inline` backend?

I'm using `matplotlib` version `3.1.3`. Also here's the `jupyter --version` output:

```
$ jupyter --version
jupyter core     : 4.6.1
jupyter-notebook : 6.0.3
qtconsole        : 4.6.0
ipython          : 7.12.0
ipykernel        : 5.1.4
jupyter client   : 5.3.4
jupyter lab      : 1.2.6
nbconvert        : 5.6.1
ipywidgets       : 7.5.1
nbformat         : 5.0.4
traitlets        : 4.3.3
```

Comment: inline uses `bbox_inches='tight'` to trim the figure to visible elements.

Comment: @JodyKlymak thanks a lot for this info! With it, I was able to find this question and the answer from it works for me: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26714626/how-to-disable-bbox-inches-tight-when-working-with-matplotlib-inline-in-ipytho

Comment: I'm guessing my question can be marked as duplicate then.

Comment: Yours is a nice illustration though...