# How do I make the width for figure 6. and Axes 4.65 with matplotlib inline_backend?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm working with matplotlib pylab backend_inline

[image]

This code set figure and Axes in different colors

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.set_facecolor('xkcd:salmon')
fig.patch.set_facecolor('k')
```

and plot this figure

[image]

so that it's easy to measure the length for the figure and Axes.

I estimated the length and got `Axes/figure` is equal to about 90%.

However, [a so post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19306776) gives this code

```
bbox = ax.get_window_extent().transformed(fig.dpi_scale_trans.inverted())
width, height = bbox.width, bbox.height
```

to get width and height of the Axes.

and I got this value

```
(4.6499999999999995, 3.0199999999999996)
```

`fig.get_size_inches()` gives `array([6., 4.])`

this code gives the same result

```
bbox = fig.get_window_extent().transformed(fig.dpi_scale_trans.inverted())
```

which results in a ratio of 77.5%, which is quite different from the ratio I measured.

However, when I saved the figure to a file,

```
plt.savefig("ax_fig_ratio")
```

I got this

[image]

which has the expected ratio.

How do I get the actual size of the figure and Axes for the first figure rendered inline?

How do I make matplotlib inline_backend render the figure in width of 6 inches and Axes in 4.65 inches, as `fig.get_size_inches()` indicates?

According to @JodyKlymak, the figure size is trimmed. If it is true, how do I disable the trimming feature so that I can get the full-size figure?

Comment: try this:`bbox = fig.get_window_extent().transformed(fig.dpi_scale_trans.inverted())` ax is the graph frame and fig is the background frame of the graph.

Comment: How did you make the first figure?  If it was with bbox_inches= tight or in the Jupyter notebook with the inline back end, the figure size is trimmed to remove extra white space which your initial call to get_window_extents doesn’t know anything about.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26714626/how-to-disable-bbox-inches-tight-when-working-with-matplotlib-inline-in-ipytho