How can I prevent matplotlib from resizing the axes dimensions to accommodate different tick values accross different figures?
I am working on a report (in LaTeX, but this problem also occurs in Word) and I am getting frustrated because I cannot figure out how to keep matplotlib from resizing the axes dimensions (the frame inside the figure) when the y-axis labels change.
The figures I am working with need to be saved in seperate files (so I cannot go about doing a subplots with a sharex parameter). They are time-based so the x-axis ticks and labels as well as the data needs to align vertically as I place the figures in my report. The y-axis limits change accross the figures and Matplotlib starts shrinking the frame dimensions when it needs to accomdate for negative signs or different magnitudes. I am using a custom mplstyle script.
What is the best way for me to go about doing this?
Below is a screenshot and the example code showing how even through the the x-axis labels are the same, the two figures are not aligned (demonstrated by red line markup).

Example code:
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.style.use("personal_repo.styles.mdpi")


fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(
    [0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
    [0, 1, 4, 9, 16],
)
fig.savefig("example1.png")

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(
    [0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
    [-4, -2, 0, 2, 4],
)
fig.savefig("example2.png")

I tried changing mplstyle parameters including the bbox (tight vs. standard), changing the subplot parameters, changing the alignment of the y-axis labels, as well as the figure.autolayout and figure.constrained_layout options (but maybe I did not correctly utilize them)
The following is the mplstyle changes:
lines.linewidth: 0.5               # line width in points
font.family: serif
font.serif: "Palatino Linotype"
font.size:    8.0
text.usetex: True  # use latex for all text handling. The following fonts
axes.linewidth: 1    # edge line width
axes.titlesize: 8.0   # font size of the axes title
axes.titlepad:      8.0     # pad between axes and title in points
axes.labelsize: 8.0  # font size of the x and y labels
                                   # according to the user's locale.
                                   # For example, use ',' as a decimal
                                   # separator in the fr_FR locale.
axes.formatter.use_mathtext: True  # When True, use mathtext for scientific
                                     # notation.

axes.prop_cycle : (cycler('color', ['k', 'r', 'b', 'g']) + cycler('ls', ['-', '--', ':', '-.']))
axes.xmargin:   .05  # x margin.  See `axes.Axes.margins`
axes.ymargin:   .05  # y margin.  See `axes.Axes.margins`
axes.zmargin:   .05  # z margin.  See `axes.Axes.margins`
axes.autolimit_mode: "round_numbers" #round_numbers  # If "data", use axes.xmargin and axes.                                         
xtick.top: True
xtick.bottom: True
xtick.major.size: 4.0
xtick.minor.size: 2.0
xtick.major.width: 1
xtick.minor.width: 1
xtick.direction: out
xtick.minor.visible: True
xtick.major.top: True
xtick.major.bottom: True
xtick.minor.top: True
xtick.minor.bottom: True
xtick.major.pad: 5.0
xtick.minor.pad: 5.0
ytick.labelsize:medium
ytick.left: True
ytick.right: True
ytick.major.size: 4.0
ytick.minor.size: 2.0
ytick.major.width: 1
ytick.minor.width: 1
ytick.direction: out
ytick.minor.visible: True
ytick.major.left: True
ytick.major.right: True
ytick.minor.left: True
ytick.minor.right: True
ytick.major.pad: 5.0
ytick.minor.pad: 5.0
xtick.labelsize:medium
grid.color: black #"#b0b0b0"  # grid color
grid.alpha:     0.1        # transparency, between 0.0 and 1.0
legend.loc:           best
legend.frameon:       True     # if True, draw the legend on a background patch
legend.framealpha:    1      # legend patch transparency
legend.edgecolor:     0     # background patch boundary color
legend.fancybox:      False     # if True, use a rounded box for the
legend.markerscale:   0.25      # the relative size of legend markers vs. original
legend.fontsize: medium
legend.handlelength:  1  # the length of the legend lines
legend.handletextpad: 0.5  # the space between the legend line and legend text
legend.columnspacing: .75  # column separation
figure.figsize: 5.6, 1.7305315203955498  # figure size in inches
figure.dpi: 300       # figure dots per inch
figure.autolayout: True  # When True, automatically adjust subplot
figure.constrained_layout.use: False  # When True, automatically make plot
savefig.dpi: 300      # figure dots per inch or 'figure'
savefig.bbox: tight    # {tight, standard}


There should be no automatic adjustments if you leave savefig.bbox as "standard" and both autolayout and constrained_layout.use as False.  However, within the notebook, the default behaviour is equivalent to savefig.bbox="tight", see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26714626/how-to-disable-bbox-inches-tight-when-working-with-matplotlib-inline-in-ipytho.

So, maybe plt.style.use("personal_repo.styles.mdpi") sets something like constrained layout?  Anyway, you could call plt.subplots_adjust(left=..., right=.., top=..., bottom=...) each time with exactly the same values (between 0 and 1, closer to zero for left and bottom, closer to 1 for top and right). You should disable autolayout and constrained_layout, as those are changing these margins constantly (adapting to adjust them to tick and axis labels).  Please add the relevant settings you tried to the post.
